# Joomla 3 Losing Sessions between HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: session, ssl, https

Our website is using Force SSL on all pages. There is a massive issue that whenever a HTTP url is requested, the session is lost and the user is logged out, even though they are still redirected to the HTTPS page.

This is really frustrating and I don't see why HTTPS sessions are lost just because an HTTP URL is requested and redirected to the HTTPS version. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found that this is a known issue as https redirection is done in the routing- after the session is instantiated - https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/4960

A simple fix is to use https redirection in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```